# MYSQL Creating dynamic queries (Pivots)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get cmb_scenarios which a grouped by date. i.e something like

```
+----------------------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| cmb_scenario                     | 2017-05-10 | 2017-05-12 | 2017-06-7 | 2018-01-01 |
+----------------------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| scenario                                |    0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |
| scenario1                       | 1047 |   549 |   637 |   492 |
| scenario2                       |    0 |     1 |     2 |     5 |
| scenario3                       |    0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |
| scenario4                       |   23 |     3 |     1 |     0 |
```

But when executing this query I keep getting "

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'scenario1,SUM( IF(DATE(datestamp) = 2018-01-08, 1,0) ) AS
>   _NULL,SUM( IF(DATE' at".

I follwed this tutorial [here](http://webdevzoom.com/dynamic-pivot-table-using-mysql/) and my query looks like this:

```
SET @sql_dynamic = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM( IF(DATE(datestamp) = ', DATE(datestamp), ', 1,0) ) AS _', DATE(datestamp))) FROM leases);

ET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT cmb_scenario, ', @sql_dynamic, ' FROM leases GROUP BY cmb_scenario WITH ROLLUP');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong because I follwed the tutorial as is.

The Coulmns are :

```
datestamp: yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
cmb_scenario: text
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat quotes around the  date(datestamp) part of = ', DATE(datestamp) and you need to replaces minus sign(-) which is returned in AS _', DATE(datestamp)